# Substitution of window variable

Tags: javascript, popup, window, window.open

In the JavaScript code there is code

```
newlyCreatedWindow = window.open(url, stageName, strWindowFeatures);
```

As even with popup blocking disabled this fails and returns NULL.

Is it possible to set newlyCreatedWindow to the current window?

Comment: Please edit your question and include the values of url, stageName & strWindowFeatures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not? I guess you want to do a "fallback"

```
if (!newlyCreatedWindow)
     newlyCreatedWindow = window;
```

(if this is not what you're thinking about, you should specify your problem)